# Update Django POST Request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If my `POST` request doesn't have a `Required field`, (say `password`), I need to set a temporary `password` to the field. Since it is set as `Required field`, we need to `update` the POST request somehow.

How can I implement it?
Also recommend if there's any alternative method

Thank in advance,

Comment: Have you tried to use `.update`?  , `request.POST.update(password='pass')`

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be:

```
my_post_data = request.POST.copy()
if 'password' not in my_post_data:
     my_pass_data['password'] = password_generation_method();
```

and use my_post_data for rest of the code. No need to play with POST data.